# PHP Script on AWS Runs at 5% instead of 100%

Tags: linux, php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

The PHP Script below is currently being hosted on a c3.large EC2 instance, with instance storage plus a SSD mount for MySQL. The file the script is reading is on one of the instance storage devices.

When the script first kicks off it runs at 100% like expected, however, after a few hours the script slows down to about 5%, ultimately slowing the MySQL inserts to a crawl.

Any ideas on whats slowing this process down? Is it possibly a IOPS issue?

```
$handle = fopen(TMP . 'zones/' . $destinationFile, 'r');
if ($handle) {
    $x = 0;
    $origin = '';
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $x = $x + 1;
        $line = str_replace("\r", '', $line);
        $line = str_replace("\n", '', $line);
        if ($x > 61) {
            $record = explode(' ', $line);
            switch ($record[1]) {
                case 'NS':
                    $domain = $record[0];
                    $nameserver = rtrim($record[2], '.');
                    if ($record[2] == $nameserver) {
                        $nameserver = $nameserver . '.' . $origin;
                    }
                    $domainId = $this->addDomain($domain, $origin);
                    $nameserverId = $this->addNameserver($nameserver);
                    $dnId = $this->addDomainNameserver($domainId, $nameserverId);
                    break;
                case 'A':
                    echo 'Nameserver IP: ' . $record[2];
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            if (strpos($line, '$ORIGIN') > -1) {
                $origin = str_replace('$ORIGIN ', '', $line);
                $origin = rtrim($origin, '.');
            }
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: Do you have enough memory? Is there swap in use? 'free -m'

Comment: Mem:   3855804k total,  3751244k used,   104560k free,   221980k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,  3170028k cached

Comment: Is that enough free memory or should I add some swap?

Answer (score 0):

Better ask on StackOverflow... You mention MySQL inserts but I don't see any SQL code in your question. Typically when you insert large amounts of data in a database:

1) you don't do one request per row
2) you COMMIT from time to time otherwise the DB has to hold all your data in a temporary buffer.
3) But you don't commit for every line either since this is expensive, typically you input data by batches of several thousands rows.

Also MySQL and other DBMS's have ways to ingest large tables from file (see [`LOAD DATA` in SQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/loading-tables.html) or the `mysqlimport` command) so your script could create that intermediate file and then call MySQL to load it in one go.